# How do i check if given username and password is what the user puts in and alert success or fail? HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

As said on title, how do i check if given username and password is what the user puts in and alert success or fail? The alert does not pop up anymore..
I embedded js script into the html file.

This is the script:

```
        function login() {
            var username = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];
            var password = ["1", "2", "3"];
            var idInput = document.getElementById("id");
            var pwInput = document.getElementById("pw");
            if (username[0] == idInput) {
                if (password[0] == pwInput) {
                    alert("login success!");
                } else if (username[1] == idInput) {
                    if (password[1] == pwInput) {
                        alert("login success!");    
                    } else if (username[2] == idInput) {
                        if (password[2] == pwInput) {
                            alert("login success!");                            
                        } else { 
                            alert("please try again"); 
                        }
                    } else { 
                        alert ("please try again");
                    } 
                } else { 
                    alert ("please try again");
                }   
            }
        }
```

And this is the body with inputs via html and the button:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Login Id:</td>
        <th>        
        <INPUT type="text" Size="40" Maxlength="35" id="id" placeholder="Your Username Here">
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <th>
        <INPUT type="text" Size="40" Maxlength="40" id="pw" placeholder="Your Password Here">
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="login()">Login</button>
```

Comment: The structure of your code is very alarming, a security issue and not expandable at all for a login system. I can only assume you are _testing_ or learning. Either way, some good foundations can go a long way and this should be re-written completely.

Comment: @Tigger exactly this. Not sure why my answer got a downvote lol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following lines. You are using the object but not the value inputted. You need to reference the value attribute of the object to get actual input.

```
var idInput = document.getElementById("id").value;
var pwInput = document.getElementById("pw").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to write this if’s is

```
if(idInput == username[0] && pwInput == password[0]){

}
else if(idInput == username[1] && pwInput == password[1]{

}

else if(idInput == username[2] && pwInput == password[2]{

}
else {
    alert(“User or password wrong.”);
}
```

If you have an variable number of users, you can do a loop:

```
function loginCheck(username, password, idInput, pwInput){
for(i = 0; i <  username.length; i++){
    if(username[i] == idInput && password[i] == pwInput)
        return 1;
}

return 0;
}
```

Now a Security issue:
Never do this check in the client side. Bad users can try to read your code and gain access. The better way is cryptograph the idInput and the pwInput with a hash (recomend SHA 256) before send thIs crypt data to the web server check (e. g. PHP). So you are protected against bad users access, and your users are protected against password leak.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you're attempting to evaluate the elements and not the value of them. Also, you have a lot of unnecessary conditionals. We also want to restructure the how we are storing our login credentials so it's more intuitive.

```js
function login() {
    // Instead of storing usernames and passwords in separate arrays,
    // we instead will store them as an array of objects with username
    // and password properties
    var logins = [
      { username: 'user1', password: '1' },
      { username: 'user2', password: '2' },
      { username: 'user3', password: '3' }
    ];
    
    // Get the values of our inputs
    var idInput = document.getElementById("id").value;
    var pwInput = document.getElementById("pw").value;
    
    // The find method on array returns the first occurrence in the
    // array if the condition evaluates to true. In this case, we
    // need to make sure the username and password match what was 
    // entered. The !== undefined determines whether or not find
    // returned a match that met the search criteria.
    const success = logins.find(login => login.username == idInput && login.password == pwInput) !== undefined;
    
    // If it found a match, then we alert the appropriate response.
    if(success) {
      alert('Successful login!');
    } else {
      alert('Failed login!');
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Login Id:</td>
        <th>        
        <INPUT type="text" Size="40" Maxlength="35" id="id" placeholder="Your Username Here">
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <th>
        <INPUT type="text" Size="40" Maxlength="40" id="pw" placeholder="Your Password Here">
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="login()">Login</button>
```

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm not following you. All of my contributions have been constructive and where they aren't I've deleted my answers rightfully so.

Comment: @DavidMakogon are you referring to the several attempts I made at addressing a zero-padding issue on matching ipv4 address? The goal of the OP was to match an IP address. I was simply addressing an oversight that someone had pointed out in the comments. It passed all test cases. From this point forward, I will make suggestions in the comments - I was unaware of the process.

Comment: @DavidMakogon most people automatically assume the accepted, most upvoted answer is correct for good reason. So me posting an answer will be buried under 20 other anwers and may not be seen even if it is a more bulletproof answer. Can you provide me with a set of rules and guidelines? I hope you can understand my actions are in good faith.